# Swift: map set of values A to B and B to A

Tags: swift, data-structures, hashmap, bidirectional-relation

**The task:**

Consider a set of values, e.g. `0, 1, 2`,
now imagine two of these sets and a bijective relation between them.

**How can I implement this in Swift, encapsulated in a data structure?**

Clarification and examples:

An example mapping could look like this:

```
0 <-> 1
1 <-> 2
2 <-> 0
```

The classic bidirectional hashmap doesn't fit to this use case well, as the values on both sides are non-unique.

The data structure should allow querying from both sides:

```
let ds = DS(...)
let ds.right(from: 1) // 2
let ds.left(from: 0) // 2
```

**What is the simplest way of implementing such data structure? What existing data types I can base my implementation on?**

**UPDATE:**

*What does "the values on both sides are non-unique”*
The values on the "Left" side are unique within that side, as well as the values on the "Right" side. However, if the value is present in one side, it will always be present in the other. Hence, the values are not unique.

*Can you give an example with non-unique values, and the expected results of right(from:) and left(from:) in the case of non-uniqueness?*

To clarify, all the values the left side has are `0,1,2`. The right side also has `0,1,2`.

**query examples:**

```
ds.rightFrom(left: 2) -> 0
ds.rightFrom(left: 0) -> 1


ds.leftFrom(right: 0) -> 2
ds.leftFrom(right: 1) -> 0
```

Comment: If the values on both sides are non-unique, does that remains Bijective Relation anymore? I think it won't

Comment: What does *"the values on both sides are non-unique”* concretely mean? Can you give an example with non-unique values, and the expected results of `right(from:)` and `left(from:)` in the case of non-uniqueness?

Comment: Related: [How would one implement a bidirectional map in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47073888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bijective function from a set to itself is a [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation). If the set consists of consecutive integers starting at zero then the permutation can be represented as an array.

In your case, the mapping from [0, 1, 2] to itself defined by

```
0 -> 1, 1 -> 2, 2 -> 0
```

would be represented as the array `[1, 2, 0]`. The “left-to-right” mapping then becomes a subscript operation:

```
let perm = [1, 2, 0]

print(perm[1]) // 2
```

The “right-to-left” mapping is the inverse permutation, and can also be represented as an array:

```
func inversePermution(of perm: [Int]) -> [Int]? {
    var inverse: [Int] = Array(repeating: -1, count: perm.count)
    for (idx, elem) in perm.enumerated() {
        // Check for valid entries:
        guard elem >= 0 && elem < perm.count else { return nil }
        // Check for duplicate entries:
        guard inverse[elem] == -1 else { return nil }
        // Set inverse mapping:
        inverse[elem] = idx
    }
    return inverse
}
```

(This is just to demonstrate the general idea. Of course you can make this an `Array` extension method, or define a `Permutation` type with this and more methods.)

In your example:

```
if let invPerm = inversePermution(of: perm) {
    print(invPerm) // [2, 0, 1]

    print(invPerm[2]) // 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip(_:_:)` on `array`, i.e.

```
let arr1 = [0,1,2]
let arr2 = [01,2,0]

let result = Array(zip(arr1,arr2))

print(result) //Output: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)]
```

Comment: Could you take a look at the example mapping between data? This wouldn't work.

Comment: See the output that I've added to the answer.

Comment: What logic are you using to get that result?

Comment: The second array is not just reversed version of first. The two have some mapping.
i.e. `1,2,0` is not a reversed version of `0,1,2`

Comment: And where does that mapping come from? Is it something random?

Comment: It's not random, but predefined. There is no logic to be found in mapping.

Comment: Updated the answer, assumed that both the `arrays` are predefined.

Comment: Still, it doesn't support random lookup

Comment: Give more clarification of your problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Code I've finished with:

```
import Foundation

public struct BidirectionalMapNonUnique<Left, Right> where Left: Hashable, Right: Hashable {
    private let ltr: [Left: Right]
    public let rtl: [Right: Left]

    public init(_ ltrMapping: [Left: Right]) {
        var rtlPending = [Right: Left]()
        for (key, value) in ltrMapping {
            rtlPending[value] = key
        }
        self.ltr = ltrMapping
        self.rtl = rtlPending
    }

    public func leftFrom(right: Right) -> Left {
        return rtl[right]!
    }

    public func rightFrom(left: Left) -> Right {
        return ltr[left]!
    }
}


let example = BidirectionalMapNonUnique<Int, Int>([0:10, 1:11, 2:12])

print(example.leftFrom(right: 11)) // Prints 1
print(example.rightFrom(left: 0)) // Prints 10
```

Comment: Is this meant to be your working solution or is this more information for your question? If this is an answer, please [edit] it and include details about what was wrong and how this fixes the problem. If this is meant to be part of your question, then please delete this "answer" and update your question.

Comment: @rmaddy This is the answer to my question I came up myself with.

Comment: *“... if the value is present in one side, it will always be present in the other.”* – That is not true for your example `[0:10, 1:11, 2:12]`

Comment: Correct, this data structure doesn't enforce such rule. Nevertheless, it can be used in this context as well (given the call site provides the correct data).

Comment: Could that be enforced at compile time?

Comment: @RichardTopchiy: Are your keys and values always from a set of consecutive numbers 0...N ? In that case it could be interpreted as a *permutation* (and its inverse).

Comment: @MartinR Interesting idea! Could you please provide a sketch of it?
Currently I use a pair of `Int` and `Enum: Int` (i.e. enum backed by an integer).

Comment: @RichardTopchiy: A permutation of the integers (0,...,N-1) can be represented as an array of size N. Your example (0->1, 1->2, 2->0) would be represented as [1,2,0]. The inverse mapping is then a permutation as well, and would in your case be represented as [2, 0, 1].

Comment: @MartinR interesting. What does the permutation array tells about the order of the elements?

Comment: @MartinR unfortunately, it's not easily applicable here since it's mapping from an Int to a custom Int-based enum (and vice-versa), not int <-> int

Comment: @RichardTopchiy: I would suggest to update your question with all that information. Make it as concrete as possible.

Comment: @MartinR I think, I'll close this question since I've found a solution that works for my case.

However, if you'd like to propose an answer with you permutation approach (I like how elegant it is), I'll accept it.